# Converting timestamp with time zone to local time in Bash

Tags: bash, time, timestamp

I am trying to do basic time math in Bash having following timestamps from OpenDj:

```
createtimestamp: 20161123165725Z
```

I don't know what time zone the system will be set with, it can be with "Zulu" timezone (UTC) as above, or might be with some other timezone. The above timestamp is for the users on LDAP servers. What I need to do is to compare the timestamp of the user with a certain timestamp.

Question: how do I convert the timestamp with zone (Z) above to local timestamp or epoch time in Bash?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Dateutils` will help

```
http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/

dateconv -i '%s' -f '%A, %d %b %Y' 1234567890

Friday, 13 Feb 2009
```

`dateutils` tools default to UTC (add -z your/timezone if needed).

Comment: Unfortunately no dateconv installed and I can not install new packages on the system. :(